# How to make a loop VBScript run silently?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript that should terminate the mspaint.exe process using a loop.

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
WScript.Sleep 3000
' Kill paint '
oShell.Run "taskkill /im mspaint.exe", , True
loop
```

It works, however every time it loops a command prompt window becomes the top-most and active window for about half a second and then closes.  This is inconvenient because I would like this to run in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmers don't run user's commands.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Do
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        If LCase(objItem.name) = "mspaint.exe" then 
                objItem.terminate
        End If
    Next
    WScript.Sleep 3000
Loop
```